# Digitize a colormap

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-image, colormap

Consider the following image:
[image: Source: https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/34863/versions/15/screenshot.jpg]

I'd like to print it as a grayscale image. I can do the conversion with `scikit-image`:

```
from skimage.io import imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray


img = imread('image.jpg')

plt.grid(which = 'both')
plt.imshow(rgb2gray(img), cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

I get:

[image]

which is [obviously not what I want](http://cresspahl.blogspot.fr/2012/03/expanded-control-of-octaves-colormap.html).

**My question is:** Is there a way with `scikit-image` or with raw `numpy` and/or `mathplotlib` to digitize the image so that I get a 3D array (first dimension: X index, second dimension: Y index, third dimension: value according to the colormap). Then I can easily change to colormap to something that turns out to have better results when printing in grayscale?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a better colormap when you generate the image. The second easist way would be to tell whoever made the image to use a better colormap. Finally, if you are really stuck with the image **and** you know exactly which colormap was used (looks like `jet`) it may be possible to create a reverse lookup table from RGB to cmap-value.

Comment: @kazemakase You're right, but I'm stuck with the image. Is there an easy way to create the reverse lookup table?

Comment: yes, there is a relatively easy way... but it is limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example below demonstrates a simple way to undo a colormap's `value -> RGB` mapping.

```
def unmap_nearest(img, rgb):
    """ img is an image of shape [n, m, 3], and rgb is a colormap of shape [k, 3]. """
    d = np.sum(np.abs(img[np.newaxis, ...] - rgb[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]), axis=-1)    
    i = np.argmin(d, axis=0)
    return i / (rgb.shape[0] - 1)
```

This function works by taking the RGB value of each pixel and looking up the index of the best matching color in the colormap. Some trickery with indexing and broadcasting allows for efficient vectorization (at the cost of memory spent on temporary arrays):

- `img[np.newaxis, ...]` converts the image from shape [n, m, 3] to [1, n, m, 3]
- `rgb[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]` converts the colormap from shape [k, 3] to [k, 1, 1, 3].
- subtracting the resulting arrays leads to an array of shape [k, n, m, 3] that contians the difference between each colormap index `k` and pixel `n, m` for each color component.
- `sum(abs(..), axis=-1)` takes the absolute value of the differences and sums over all color components (the last dimension) to get the total difference between all pixels and color map entries (array of shape [k, n, m]).
- `i = np.argmin(d, axis=0)` finds the index of the minimum element along the first dimension. The result is the index of the best matching color map entry of each pixel [n, m].
- `return i / (rgb.shape[0] - 1)` finally returns the indices normalized by the color map size so that the result is in range 0-1.

[image]

There are a faw caveats with this approach:

1. It cannot reconstruct the original value range.
2. It will treat all pixels as part of the color map (i.e. continent contuors will also be mapped).
3. If you use the wrong color map it will fail hilariously.

.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray


def unmap_nearest(img, rgb):
    """ img is an image of shape [n, m, 3], and rgb is a colormap of shape [k, 3]. """
    d = np.sum(np.abs(img[np.newaxis, ...] - rgb[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]), axis=-1)    
    i = np.argmin(d, axis=0)
    return i / (rgb.shape[0] - 1)


cmap = plt.cm.jet
rgb = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, cmap.N))[:, :3]


original = (np.arange(10)[:, None] + np.arange(10)[None, :])

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(original, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('original')


plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
rgb_img = cmap(original / 18)[..., :-1]
plt.imshow(rgb_img)
plt.title('color-mapped')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
wrong = rgb2gray(rgb_img)
plt.imshow(wrong, cmap='gray')
plt.title('rgb2gray')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
reconstructed = unmap_nearest(rgb_img, rgb)
plt.imshow(reconstructed, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('reconstructed')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit the trickery with `d` and `i` in your `unmap_nearest` function?

Comment: In my use case, I think I need to get rid of the world map.

Comment: @cjorssen I edited the question to explain the function step by step. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: You can use (c)KDTree https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html  to find the nearest  quicker that also allows you to restrict color remapping to only point near enough to the Cmap: http://carreau.github.io/posts/24-Viridisify.html

Comment: Definitely worth looking into if the quick&dirty approach does not suffice.

Comment: This brute force approach worked really well for me. For an implementation in a jupyter notebook check out https://github.com/svaberg/imageslurper

Comment: @Svaberg nice! I think you could increase vividness of the example by plotting the reconstruction in a different colormap. (Currently, one could believe it was the original RGB image just plotted with matplotlib.)

Comment: @kazemakase That's a great suggestion! I followed it; it looks a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @kazemakmakase's answer, if you're digitizing a figure, you probably are dealing with a copy of the original that's been converted, or maybe even printed and scanned at some point. Those things can distort colors from the "true" colormap that was originally used.

You can deal with this by using a slice through the figure's colorbar as the 'pattern' (rgb) to match against. Specifically, crop the figure down to just the color ramp (in landscape orientation in this example), then replace the `rgb` variable in @kazemakmakase's example with:

```
cmapimg = plt.imread('cropped_colorbar.png')
rgb = cmapimg[cmapimg.shape[0]/2,:,:3]
```